# base.apk code is missing after registerTransform in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, transform

github [address](https://github.com/HakuLess/Kiana)

```
registerTransform(TestTransForm())

class TestTransForm : Transform() {
override fun getName(): String {
    return "test"
}

override fun getInputTypes(): MutableSet<QualifiedContent.ContentType> {
    return mutableSetOf(QualifiedContent.DefaultContentType.CLASSES)
}

override fun isIncremental(): Boolean {
    return false
}

override fun getScopes(): MutableSet<in QualifiedContent.Scope> {
    return TransformManager.SCOPE_FULL_PROJECT
}

override fun transform(transformInvocation: TransformInvocation?) {
}}
```

I just try an empty Transform, doesn't work either. I check the .class file in output, the .class file actually changed as expected. But error occurs when installing apk, log :

```
Failed to commit install session 1402092649 with command cmd package install-commit 1402092649. Error: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.haku.aaa-3aSlvL5yaZujUqYNmZlzgQ==: Package /data/app/com.haku.aaa-3aSlvL5yaZujUqYNmZlzgQ==/base.apk code is missing
```

Then I tried some examples like [Example](https://github.com/ytinrete/AndroidTransformAPIandAOPExample), it works well. I thought the version of Gradle and Gradle tools is the reason, but still report the error after I changed tools version & wrapper version.

Gradle Tools Version: 3.1.4
Wrapper Version: gradle-5.1

Answer (score 1):

You must be responsible for writing the input to the output in the method `transform`,

```
@Override
void transform(
        @NonNull TransformInvocation transformInvocation) throws TransformException, InterruptedException, IOException {
    def inputs = transformInvocation.inputs
    def outputProvider = transformInvocation.outputProvider
    inputs.each { TransformInput input ->
        input.directoryInputs.each {DirectoryInput dirInput ->
            println("transform DirectoryInput:" + directoryInput.getFile().absolutePath);

            //do your work here,modify classes in the dirInput.

            //Make sure to copy every input to output,no matter modified or not.
            File dest = outputProvider.getContentLocation(directoryInput.getName(),
                    directoryInput.getContentTypes(), directoryInput.getScopes(), Format.DIRECTORY);
            println("transform DirectoryOutput:" + dest.getAbsolutePath());
            FileUtils.copyDirectory(directoryInput.getFile(), dest);
        }
        input.jarInputs.each{ JarInput jarInput ->
            println("transform jarInput:" + jarInput.getFile().absolutePath);
            String destName = jarInput.getName();

            //Do your work here,modify the jarInput.

            //Make sure to copy every input to output,no matter modified or not.
            File dest = outputProvider.getContentLocation(destName,
                    jarInput.getContentTypes(), jarInput.getScopes(), Format.JAR);
            println("transform jarOutput:" + dest.getAbsolutePath());
            FileUtils.copyFile(jarInput.getFile(), dest);
        }

    }
}
```

Sample code snipet is groovy,you can convert to kotlin easily.

Read the [document](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/javadoc/3.1/com/android/build/api/transform/Transform.html) for the detailed instructions.